# Saving values ​in SharedPreference from my model class with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, model, sharedpreferences

I have a question that I think is pretty basic.

I'm doing my model class on a test application at Kotlin.

This is my code:

```
class Persona(name :String, age :Int) {

    val CUSTOM_PREF_NAME = "App_data"
    val prefs = customPreference(MainApplication.applicationContext(), CUSTOM_PREF_NAME)

    var name :String = name
        get() = "The name: $field" 
        set(value) {
            prefs.saveName = value
        }

    var age: Int = age
        get() = field
        set(value) {
          field = value
        }
}
```

What I want is that between the brackets of the var name set, the value is saved in SharedPreferences.

I didn't succeed and I think I got the theory wrong.

In the brackets of the set I couldn't even execute a simple log.

I can't run anything from there?
How would I save a value in SharedPreferences from the set? Using sharedPreferences from any other point in the app works fine,.

I think I'm a little lost here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the code in your setter for `name` is never called? It won't be called at instantiation, but it should be if you try to change the value of `name`. Incidentally, since your getter only looks at the backing field, getting the value will always retrieve the initial value, even if you've set a different value.

Comment: In my main activity I have a button to change the value of the name, but when I do: persona.name = "Arthur" persona.age = 20, what is between the square brackets of the set "prefs.saveName = value" does not run .. I'm going crazy! Thanks for the get notice, it doesn't matter at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var name :String = name
    get() = "The name: $field" 
    set(value) {
        field = value
        prefs.saveName = value
    }
```